# How configure keybinding for Yasnippet only?

Tags: yasnippet

When you insert a snippet from Yasnippet, you have this, for example

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# $1 (`(insert-date)`)
# --------------------------------------------------------------
$2
```

Then you press tab, to switch from the place `$1` to the place `$2`.

If you are not in a snippet, the tab key works normal.

I figured out the function that's get called when you press `Tab` into snippet, is `yas-next-field`. I would like to bind the function to another key instead `Tab`.

But only when it's inside a snippet, not affecting the normal working of another key outside snippet, like `Tab` already is.

But I couldn't find any refefence on internet about keymapping for only inside yasnippet, not as normal key.

Thanks in advance for the suggestion, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customize `yas-keymap` for that.

```
(eval-after-load 'yasnippet
  '(progn
     (define-key yas-keymap (kbd "TAB") nil)
     (define-key yas-keymap (kbd "C-o") 'yas-next-field-or-maybe-expand)))
```

Comment: Thanks Wasamasa! That worked it right. But how could you figure that out, if I might ask? I found nothing about that on Yasnippet documentation.

Comment: I've read the source code and found three keymaps, one of which was using `yas-next-field-or-maybe-expand`.

Comment: Reading the source code, that could be an option too... would be a hell of job for me personally. I still have some difficulties to understand Elisp code. I'm planning to learn Elisp at the end of April. Thanks Wasama, it's really appreciated.